# PHP: Submit form passing page name to action

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using a simple page switch in my project to change page in menù, the page url sounds like domain.com/index.php?page=some.

I must to submit a form to self page and append the form values to the url using GET or POST, so was tried to use `<form action="index.php?page=some$var=some" method="GET">` expecting PHP automatically append the input values, but nothing goes as expected cause I've been redirected to `index.php?`.
So I've tried to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` but got the same result.

**That's the question:** Assuming I must to post the form to the same page, how I can pass the page variable and instead the form data?

Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: `<form action="">`

Comment: Same result, redirected in index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hidden fields in the form. Something like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $some; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<form action="index.php" method="GET">` and add those variables as hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="some">
```

Then leave the rest of the form as it is.

This way you are including the `"page=some"`variable and also the rest of the form values.